# Mocha tests don't run with Webpack and mocha-loader

Tags: npm, reactjs, mocha.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

### Background

I am porting some npm scripts to Webpack loaders to better learn how Webpack works and I’ve got everything working except for my Mocha tests: I have one failing test, but it is not showing that Mocha is being run with the `mocha-loader` or that the test is failing:

[image]

### Question

What do I need to do differently to get all `src/**/*.test.js` files to run with with Mocha in Webpack?

## Steps to reproduce

1. Clone https://github.com/trevordmiller/webpack-loaders-playground
2. Run `npm test` to see how tests should work
3. Run `npm run dev` to see how tests don't run with Webpack

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Mocha loader won't run tests while building, it's used to create a bundle specifically containing your tests which you can then run from your browser.

I would recommend creating a separate webpack config file for your tests, which you can then host on a webpack-dev-server that uses a different port from your application. Here's an example that's more-or-less the pattern that I use for my own projects (as of writing this answer):

### webpack.tests.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: 'mocha!./tests/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'test.build.js',
        path: 'tests/',
        publicPath: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/tests'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /(\.css|\.less)$/,
                loader: 'null-loader',
                exclude: [
                    /build/
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/,
                loader: 'null-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        host: hostname,
        port: port
    }
};
```

### tests/index.js

```js
// This will search for files ending in .test.js and require them
// so that they are added to the webpack bundle
var context = require.context('.', true, /.+\.test\.js?$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
module.exports = context;
```

### package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "find ./ -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha -R min -r babel/register",
    "devtest": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.tests.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js"
}
```

### test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mocha</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
        <script src="/tests/test.build.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then run `npm run devtest`, open `http://localhost:<port you picked>/webpack-dev-server/test.html`, and mocha should run your tests.

If you don't require CSS/LESS or images through your modules, you can remove those loaders from `webpack.tests.config.js`.

With hot loading enabled this is a really great setup because I can have both my application and my tests running in different browser tabs, then update my code and see my changes and my tests re-running immediately.

You can also run `npm run test` to execute the same tests through the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach requires you to remember to list all tests in a centralized index file. If you forget, the test will never be run. Alternative approaches (which involve configuring *Mocha* to ignore Webpack features), don't require you to maintain a centralized list of tests. I suggest this approach instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881123/handle-webpack-css-imports-when-testing-with-mocha-and-babel?rq=1

Comment: I updated my answer a while ago with a better version of index.js that doesn't require you to import every test module. You can use `require.context` to scan for all of your tests.

Comment: Great point Jim, I missed that! That said, I went this route because it avoids having to setup a dedicated webpack.config for tests: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/commit/16ec28c9029bf7e2b65b26c22a1c2daadab427a2

Comment: @JimSkerritt I try the cli 'find ./ -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha -R min -r babel/register', it says can not find module babel/resgiter.

Comment: do you have a simple .test.js file that I can refer to and learn how you write it?

Comment: Nice solution. I have one problem though: I have different files containing tests and when webpack-dev-server does its hot reload only one result from one test file are actually shown. If I refresh manually I can see all results from all tests again. Do you face the same issue and if so did you find a solution?

Comment: If I'm running two Webpack webservers, does the one running Mocha have its own UI that I don't have to create myself? Am I essentially creating one entrypoint with Mocha and one without? How does it handle the route as `/webpack-dev-server/test` if you're proxying in the dev server config like so: '*': { target: config.getProxyServerUrl() }?

Comment: @JimSkerritt the `npm run test` will work if you replace `babel/register` with `babel-register` in `'find ./ -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha -R min -r babel/register'`, thanks for your helpful and detailed answer to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

I liked JimSkerritt's answer, but couldn't get it to work on my computer for some reason. With the two config files below you can run the app via:

```
npm start              // then http://localhost:8080/bundle
```

and run your tests with:

```
npm test              // then http://localhost:8081/webpack-dev-server/test
```

both servers auto-reload && you can run both simultaneously!

## Config Files

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    }
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "2dpointfinder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline",
    "test": "webpack-dev-server 'mocha!./tests/test.js' --output-filename test.js --port 8081"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "mocha-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "should": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```