# How to run mocha tests with webpack when you don't have a single entry point to tests?

Tags: mocha.js, webpack

I'm trying to convert a project from `browserify`+`mochify` to `webpack`.

The [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#karma-and-webpack) demonstrate how to use `mocha-loader` to run the tests with `webpack-dev-server`, but assumes a single entry point into the tests.

All the existing tests were designed with [`mochify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochify) in mind which does not require a single entry point as it recursively bundles `./test/*.js`.

Answer (score 2):

The setup below sort of works for me. It still uses `mochify` to run the tests (because it has all the phantomjs interfacing), but doesn't rely on anything from `browserify`. If you run `webpack --watch`, it reruns all tests when a file changes.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");
var child_process = require('child_process');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    tests: "./tests.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "tests.js", // Should be a unique name
    path: "/tmp"
  },
  plugins: [
    // Automatically run all tests when webpack is done
    function () {
      this.plugin("done", function (stats) {
        child_process.execSync('mochify /tmp/tests.js', { stdio: 'inherit'});
      });
    }
  ],
};
```

`tests.js`:

```
// List all test dirs here if you have multiple
var contexts = [
  require.context('./dir1/test', true, /\.js$/),
  require.context('./dir2/test', true, /\.js$/)
];
contexts.forEach(function (context) {
  context.keys().forEach(context);
});
```

Another approach is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386750/675011

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, but it solved the problem for me. The reason I wanted to combine mochify and webpack was that I wanted to use the browser console to debug my mocha tests. Since my mocha tests themselves don't rely on a browser, it was enough for me to finally realize I could use a node debugger and it would bring up the Chrome console, (almost) solving my problem. [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector%20node-inspector) is the node debugger, but I'm using babel, so I needed babel-node-debug, but that doesn't yet work with babel6, but there's an unmerged pull request that fixes it: https://github.com/CrabDude/babel-node-debug/pull/12.

Comment: Debugging with mocha is having further complications. `bode-debug _mocha index.js` is sort of working for me.