# angular + mocha + typescript + webpack testing

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, mocha.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a large Angular project written in Typescript which is turned into a bundle by Webpack. When using Karma I have been getting a [page reload issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1656) which I cannot resolve. Therefore I have switched to trying Mocha but I cannot get this to work properly. I have followed the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385219/mocha-tests-dont-run-with-webpack-and-mocha-loader) to get me this far.

**First problem**

Perhaps someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me the right way to set this up.

I run the webpack-dev-server for testing like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.test.config.js
```

This gives me a web page where I can see the test run output. If I change any of my Typescript the bundle is rebuilt and the hot module reload kicks in but then I get an error on the web page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at callFn (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8459:9), <anonymous>:4471:20)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8459:9), <anonymous>:4464:7)
    at next (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8459:9), <anonymous>:4810:10)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8459:9), <anonymous>:4832:5)
    at timeslice (eval at <anonymous> (test/test.build.js:8459:9), <anonymous>:75:27)
```

If I refresh the page then the tests run again.

**Second problem**

My directive test that used to work now breaks because the scope object is not the same as it used to be. The scope I pass into the `$compile` function does not have the directive's functions on it. These are now on `scope.$$childTail`
I don't know if this is a side-effect of switching to Mocha or something I have done wrong.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map', //just do inline source maps instead of the default
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
          {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json',
          },
          {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader',
            //loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react!ts-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            //loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react!ts-loader'
          },
        {
            test: /masonry|imagesloaded|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/,
            loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'
        }
        ],
      },
      resolve: {
        root: [ path.resolve('./ng/ng') ],
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css'],
       alias: {
           'react-dom': 'react/lib/ReactDOM',
      //    'react$'      : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js'),
          'react/addons': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-addons/index.js'),
          'xeditable.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css'),
          'textAngular.css': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/textangular/dist/textAngular.css'),
       }
      },
      externals: {
        'cheerio': 'window',
        'react': 'React',
        'react-addons': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'react-dom/server': true,
        //'react-addons-test-utils': true,
        'ChemDoodle': true,
        //'react': true,
        //'react/addons': true,
        //'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
        //'react/lib/ReactContext': true
      },
      entry: {
               itracker: './ng/ng/app.ts',
      },
      output: {
        //path: '.',
        //publicPath: '/website/js/',
        path: path.resolve('.'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/', // Tell django to use this URL to load packages and not use STATIC_URL + bundle_name
        //filename: 'itracker.bundle.js'
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if there is an error
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        //new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        // Export a global jQuery
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      })
      ]
}
```

**webpack.test.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const index = path.resolve(__dirname, './test/test_index.js');

config.entry = { tests: 'mocha!'+ index };

config.module.loaders = [
        {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /masonry|imagesloaded|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/,
            loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'
        },
        {
            test: /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/,
            loader: 'null-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /(\.css|\.less|\.scss)$/,
            loader: 'null-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + __dirname + '&prefix=/website/js!html'
        }
];

// config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
//     // keeps hashes consistent between compilations
//     new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

// ]);

config.output = {
    filename: 'test.build.js',
    path: 'test/',
    publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/test',
};

config.devServer = {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    }
};

config.target = 'web';

module.exports = config;
```

**test_index.js**

```
// Add all tests to context so they are put in bundle
const context = require.context('.', true, /.+[st]\.spec\.tsx?$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);

// Add all partials to context so they are put in bundle
var templates = require.context('../partials', true, /\.html$/);
templates.keys().forEach(function(key) {  
  templates(key);
});

module.exports = context;
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mocha</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />

        <script src="/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

        <script src="/test/test.build.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```