# ReferenceError: WebGLRenderingContext is not defined

Tags: typescript, webpack, mocha.js, webgl

**Context:**

I'm coding a personal WebGL Api using Typescript with Webpack. WebGL stuffs renders correctly in the browser.

> Everything is ok !

Now, trying to create some unit tests following this setup with mocha :

[Unit testing node applications with TypeScript — using mocha and chai](https://journal.artfuldev.com/unit-testing-node-applications-with-typescript-using-mocha-and-chai-384ef05f32b2)

`mocha --reporter list -r ts-node/register -r jsdom-global/register 'test/**/*.spec.ts'`

[image: Mocha result]

> Everything is also ok !

**Problem :**

Until I try to test a code which references `WebGLRenderingContext`where the following error arise:

```
   ReferenceError: WebGLRenderingContext is not defined
    at D:\JEROME\dev\repositories\experiment_typescript\webgl_api\src\webgl_objects\datas\webgl_enum_indexed.ts:7:34
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\JEROME\dev\repositories\experiment_typescript\webgl_api\src\webgl_objects\datas\webgl_enum_indexed.ts:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\JEROME\dev\repositories\experiment_typescript\webgl_api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:837:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\JEROME\dev\repositories\experiment_typescript\webgl_api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:840:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
```

[image: Mocha result]

> Breaking > Not ok !

**I don't understand how to make it works, any suggestion ?**

- Am I missing some way to link reference ?
- Should I investigate in another way of testing ?

**Here is my configurations :**

package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gl-matrix": "^3.2.1",
    "wasm-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "latest",
    "@types/html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.2",
    "@types/jsdom": "latest",
    "@types/mocha": "latest",
    "@types/webgl2": "~0.0.5",
    "canvas": "^2.6.1",
    "chai": "latest",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "del-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "jsdom": "16.3.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "mocha": "latest",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./custom_typings",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./web/**/*",
    "./src/**/*",
    "./custom_typings",
    "./node_modules/@types",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long way searching informations, and thanks to gman answer, I saw this in another way and I manage to publish my tests with Webpack using npm mocha-loader.

`"mocka_browser_test": "del-cli dist && webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.config.test.ts"`

with an other webpack.config file dedicated to test :
[image]

This can be related to this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385219/mocha-tests-dont-run-with-webpack-and-mocha-loader).

This wasn't easy to combine informations found around the web for someone who is new to the typescript/npm puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit tests are running in node.js via mocha. node.js does not support WebGL just like it doesn't support most of the browser's APIs.

You can use mocha inside [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) if you want to run tests that use browser APIs. The [examples page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/examples) of that puppeteer article links to [an example of using mocha with puppeteer](https://github.com/direct-adv-interfaces/mocha-headless-chrome).

Comment: This helped me to understand I had to see it with another way. Finally I used Webpack and mocha-loader to publish my tests too. But I probably will have to go with your solution if my needs grows and if an external API is needed. Thank you for your answer !